# Column name with max value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below sample dataset:

[image]

I want to get the name of the column that has the maximum value, in this case 'C'. `MAX` doesn't return the desired result as it cant be used with multiple columns.

```
SELECT MAX(A,B,C,D)
FROM TABLE
```

*Could someone pls help.*

Comment: What is your expected output if there are multiple column with MAX values?

Comment: Hello @Newbie does any of the answers help you with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with union and max:

```
with cte as( select a as col, 'A' col_name
             from Data
             union 
             select b, 'B' col_name
             from Data
             union
             select c, 'C' col_name
             from Data
             union
             select d, 'D' col_name
             from Data
) select * 
  from cte
  where col = (select max(col) 
               from cte);
```

Result:

```
| col | col_name |
+-----+----------+
| 400 |    C     |
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aff6ce37fa4c955af3c52ffa0f990696)

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is the following statement, using `VALUES` table value constructor:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (A int, B int, C int, D int)
INSERT INTO Data (A, B, C, D) VALUES (50, 100, 400, 200)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.*, c.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 v.ColumnName, v.ColumnValue
   FROM (VALUES 
      ('A', d.A), 
      ('B', d.B), 
      ('C', d.C), 
      ('D', d.D)
   ) v (ColumnName, ColumnValue)
   ORDER BY v.ColumnValue DESC
) c
```

Result:

```
A   B   C   D   ColumnName  ColumnValue
50  100 400 200 C           400
```

If the table has multiple `max` values in one row, you may use the following statement:

```
SELECT d.*, c.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT v.ColumnName, v.ColumnValue, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY v.ColumnValue DESC) AS RN
   FROM (VALUES 
      ('A', d.A), 
      ('B', d.B), 
      ('C', d.C), 
      ('D', d.D)
   ) v (ColumnName, ColumnValue)
) c
WHERE c.RN = 1
```